# How do I set the fixed height for each smartphone?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive

I'm a junior front-end developer.

Header and footer areas are fixed

I want to dynamically set the height of the "box container".

If this dynamic height is higher than the set height, I want to make it scroll.

If the total height of the device is 600px and the height of the header and footer is 100px, I want to set the height of the "box container" to 400px

I want to make it scroll when the height of the box container goes over the footer element

```
 a PHONE (600px)
 ----- 
 HEADER (100px)
 -----
 
 BOXCONTAINER (SCROLL) (400px overflow scroll)

 -----
 FOOTER (100px)
 -----
 
 another page
 -----
 HEADER (100px)
 -----

 ANOTHER ELEMENT (200px)
 
 BOXCONTAINER (SCROLL overflow scroll) (200px)

 -----
 FOOTER (100px)
 -----
```

this is example code

```
 <div className="App">
      <header>this is header</header>
      <div>.... another content....</div>
      <div className="boxContainer">
        <div className="box" />
        <div className="box" />
        <div className="box" />
        <div className="box" />
        <div className="box" />
        <div className="box" />
        <div className="box" />
        <div className="box" />
        <div className="box" />
        <div className="box" />
        <div className="box" />
        <div className="box" />
        <div className="box" />
      </div>
      <footer>this is footer</footer>
    </div>

.boxContainer {
  /* how do i get the dynamic height??? */
  height: 300px; // or 200px or 500px ... 
  overflow : scroll;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

.box:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

What should I do?

I thought about adding px values of the header and footer area for every page, subtracting the total height of the device, and giving the content element a fixed height in inline-style. However, using this method, every page had to be set up (because there might be other elements except header and footer). I thought this wasn't the way.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without JS and some shinanigans it is hard, but You are using react so You can calculate everything after component did mount and set height of boxContainer acordingly:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.App > *:not(.boxContainer)');
    var height = 0;
    for (const element of elements.values()) {
        let style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
      height += parseInt(style.height);
    }
    document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--box-container-height', height+'px');
    /* 
    other way would be using state variable
    this.setState({ 
      boxContainerHeight : `calc(100vh - ${height}px)`
    }) */
  }
```

Set state is antipattern (it calls render() method second time), so better use css vars.
full demo: https://jsfiddle.net/m9rqsL4j/13/

Answer (score 0):

Use Viewport Height property.

```
header {
  height: 4vh ;
}

.boxContainer {
  height: /* your preference */;
  /* height: 92vh ; */
  overflow:auto;
}

footer {
  height: 4vh ;
}
```

You can try using Percentage values, but i prefer viewport height.